# Android list process

Tags: android, linux, pid, ps

I was wondering how can I check the last application executed by the user in Android Phone (in terminal). I was checking with `ps` command but no timestamp is shown. What I want to get is the PID of the last application executed by the user.

Any suggestion?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use

```
adb logcat
```

and check for the last user application which was executed (the pid is in the brackets). I doubt there's an more reliable way to retrieve this information as there might a lot of background process (own pid, own user) involved or running without connection to the last user process.

Comment: Thanks for the info HefferWolf!!

But how can I filter all the data generated by adb logcat in order to detect which one was the las application executed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You should also note that for fetching such info you'll probably have to have a rooted phone